# How to print a file, excluding comments and blank lines, using grep/sed?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I'd like to print out a file containing a series of comments like:

```
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
    #   SSL Engine Switch:
```

In essence, the file contains multiple indentation levels, where a comment starts with a `#` symbol.

grep should remove blank lines, and also lines where there is a hash symbol before text (implying that these are comments).

I know that blank lines can be deleted via: `grep -v '^$'`

However how can I delete lines with leading whitespace, and then a `#` symbol, and print out only lines with actual code? I would like to do this in bash, using grep and/or sed.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
grep -v '^\s*$\|^\s*\#' temp
```

On OSX / BSD systems:

```
grep -Ev '^\s*$|^\s*\#' temp
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to catch cases where the comments have leading whitespace, keep in mind.

Comment: It will not work if there are lines which are having only white spaces (space, tab etc).

Below worked for me.

`egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$|^ *#' <file_name>`

Comment: `egrep -v '^[[:blank:]]*#|^[[:blank:]]*$' <file_name>`  newline, vertical tab, form feed, and carriage return are not part  of a line in grep (by default) and blank could occur in *empty* lines

Comment: Why is the `|` being escaped? This did not work for me on ZSH. Instead I had to do: `grep -v "^$|^\s*\#"`

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, you may not need to escape the `|`, however I suspect this has more to do with your version of grep (e.g. BSD vs GNU) than your choice of shell.

Comment: Apologies, it does actually work for me. I forgot I had ripgrep aliased to grep.

Comment: Did not work on OSX, removed comments but not newlines.

Comment: Updated the answer to cover whitespace-only lines and OSX/BSD systems.

Answer (score 29):

With `awk`:

```
awk '!/^ *#/ && NF' file
```

- `!/^ *#/` - means select lines which do not have space followed by `#` symbol
- `NF` - means select lines which are not blank
- `&&` - is an `and` operator which ensure if both of the above are true then print the line.

Answer (score 10):

This is probably easier with `sed` than `grep`:

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' -e '/^[[:space:]]*#/d' test.in
```

Or with an ERE:

```
# Gnu sed need -re instead of -Ee
sed -Ee '/^[[:space:]]*(#|$)/d' test.in
```

With the ERE, grep can do it fairly easily too:

```
# Not sure if Gnu grep needs -E or -r
grep -vE '^\s*(#|$)' test.in

# or a BRE
grep -v '^\s*\(#\|$\)' test.in
```

Comment: Is this the simplest form?

Comment: You can do it somewhat nicer with an extended regex, see my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Little Upgrade

`grep -v '^\s*$\|^#\|^\s*\#' filename`

This code excludes empty lines or lines with only spaces, lines beginning with #, and lines containing nothing but spaces before #.

PS: `^#` is different than `^\s*#`

Comment: Would you care to explain how `^#` is different from `^\s*#`?

Comment: `^#` -> only match hastag letter on beginning of the line <br/>
`^\s*#` -> also match hastag letter with spaces before

Comment: It's redundant. `/s*` means "match 0 or more spaces". Thus `^\s*#` would also match `^#`.

Answer (score 5):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r '/^(\s*#|$)/d;' file
```

---

```
$cat file
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    next line is empty

       line with leading space
       # line with leading space and #
    LogLevel warn
        #line with leading tab and #
        line with leading tab
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
    #   SSL Engine Switch:
$sed -r '/^(\s*#|$)/d;' file
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    next line is empty
       line with leading space
    LogLevel warn
        line with leading tab
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
```

Answer (score 4):

This one should do:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*#.*//;/^[[:space:]]*$/d' file
```

On this input:

```
Hello everybody

# This is a comment and the previous line was empty

This is a genuine line followed by a comment # this is the comment


              # and here a comment in the middle of nowhere
```

you'll obtain this output:

```
Hello everybody
This is a genuine line followed by a comment
```

*Caveat.* This kind of method is not 100% foolproof: if you have a pound sign (`#`) not starting a comment, i.e., it's escaped or inside a string, well, you can imagine what will happen.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Your solution is the only one work to remove CSF # do not delete string that also has another pound sign between, so it will only output an IP addrress. Thanks for providing this alternative answer

Answer (score 3):

```
grep ^[^#] filename
```

- `^` - begin of line
- `[^#]`- exclude #.

If you have spaces in the begin of line it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Can't think of anything simpler than:

```
grep -v '^ *#\|^$' filename
```

You can test with this file:

```
# comment
 # comment with space before
  # comment with two spaces before
line with text and # comment at the end

line with text
```

(edited to include a ' *' and handle comments with leading spaces)

Comment: That wont work when there are spaces beforce the comment characters.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple one-liner grep. This will get rid of hashes and empty lines.

```
grep -ve '^#' -ve '^$' /path/to/the/file
```

have fun.

Answer (score 1):

`egrep -v '^$|^#' /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: plz explain your answer in simple words, instead of posting the code only

Comment: This does not work on /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^\s*[^#]\|^$/!'p filename
```

Pattern will match any amount of whitespaces (or zero) starting at the beginning of the line and following by any character that is not a #
OR empty string (nothing at all in between ^ and $).
To NOT match it, sed allows the usage of **!** operator (invert match). Now pattern matches anything that regular expression don't fits in.
Thus with combination of **-n** (suppress of printing anything) and **p** flag (print) lines matching anything except the pattern will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Using default space separator

- empty line or line with *blank* only have an empty $1
- line with first non *blank*¨char is #, have $1 starting with #

so, keep it simple

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[^#]/ ' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v '^$\|^#\|^\s*\#' filename
```

Excludes empty lines, lines beginning with # and lines containing nothing but spaces before #.

Comment: This is really the same as the accepted answer. `^#` is redundant as `^\s*#` matches zero or more whitespace followed by a hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash


#---------------------------------------------------------------#
#             Programacion Shell                                #
#             ------------------                                #
#  Programa:  xable.sh  (eXecutABLEs)                           #
###                                                           ###
#  OBJETIVO:  Filtrar solo las lineas ejecutables de un shell   #
#                                    (eXecutABLEs)              #
###                                                           ###
#  Autor...:  Francisco Eugenio Cabrera Perez                   #
#  Pais....:  Republica Dominicana                              #
#  Fecha...:  Abril 6 del 2015                                  #
#---------------------------------------------------------------#

         x_FILE=$1
if [ -z $x_FILE ];then
   echo
   echo "      $0 :  Sin Argumento^G"; echo
   echo "USO:  $0 ARCHIVO";            echo
###
   exit 1
fi
#####


#  Ignore COMMENTs and lines that...
#  ---------------------------------
#      EXPLANATION                            (PATTERN)         OBSERVATION
#      -----------                            ---------         -----------
#  1.  Begin_and_End_with_NOTHING             (^$)              NO_Characters
###
#  2.  Begin_with_HASH_symbol                 (^#)              COMMENT
#  3.  Begin_with_SPACE_and_then_HASH_symbol  (^\s*\#)          COMMENT
###
#  4.  Begin_and_End_with_SPACES              (^[[:space:]]*$)  Only_SPACES
#  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#####
    grep -v '^$\|^#\|^\s*\#' $x_FILE | grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$" | more
#####
```

Comment: Show me only eXecutABLEs lines  ( xable.sh )

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v '^$\|^#\|^\s*\#' filename | grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$" | more
```

Comment: Show me only eXecutABLEs lines

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the commands are intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

With Perl:

```
perl -lne 'print if ! /^\s*(#.*)?$/' file
```

This will also ignore C++ comments (//)

```
perl -lne 'print if ! m{^\s*((#|//).*)?$}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
grep -v '^#\|^$\|^\s+$' file
```

Would hide lines beginning with `#`, empty lines and lines that only contain white spaces from be printed out to the stdout. Notice that the `|` character has to be escaped. Hope that helps

Comment: This also does not handle leading whitespace `   #`, which technically is a comment too.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy it does handle leading whitespaces, the `^\s+$` part takes care of that

Comment: but not leading whitespace + comment after that ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy I see what you are saying, you are right, working on a fix, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> grep -v ^$ file.txt | grep -v ^\#
> ```

First grep will remove line starting with an EOF (empty lines in English), second will remove all commented lines

Comment: EOF is end of file?

Answer (score -1):

```
cat filename| egrep -v "^\s*$|^;|^\s*#
```

- First, `cat` the file
- `egrep -v` removes
- `^$` starting with empty line
- `^;` starting with `;`
- `^\s` matches any leading whitespace, then any character until `#`

Comment: this is a very bad use of the `cat` command, you could just use `egrep` without the cat